# Module default implementation standard?

Tags: python, module, default, default-value

Is there a golden standard to implement default values in python modules if there are lots of defaults? I tend to use classes with the defaults stored as static values.

```
"""
__init__.py
"""
class Default(object):
    class Address(object):
        server = "https://stackoverflow.com"

    class SomeValues(object):
        bar = 3

default_Server = Default.Address.server
```

This way I can group them and easily access them. However, I am not sure  whether this is good style or if there is a better or more common way to implement this.

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. You might want to change the question a bit to make it more specific - do you have particular problems with your method?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a preferred method.. I tend to include a `defaults.json` file or create a dictionary with all the entries I need, and package it with `pickle` along with my module.

Comment: @Gareth Latty. I edited the question. I want to know about the existence of a standard.

Comment: @DanielBöckenhoff Sure, but, as far as I know, I think the answer is there is no one standard - it's likely to be very dependent on what your needs are.

Comment: @Gareth Latty: Than this is would be the answer already. If you are sure about this, make it an answer and i will accept.

Comment: @DanielBöckenhoff I'm not *that* certain about it. Someone else can take this one.

Comment: Daniel: It looks to me like what you're try to accomplish could be done by reading a configuration file that supplies the needed default values, which can be handled in a number of different ways. Python comes with a [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) module and there are some very good third-party utilities like [`configobj`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) that do something similar. Folks also use JSON files and Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module to read their contents.

Comment: @martineau: I will have a look into that.